# Auto increase the height of relative div if the height of inner absolute div increases?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html,

```
<div id="content">

<div id="leftcol">
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>

</div>
```

with following css,

```
#content {
width: 780px;
padding: 10px;
position: relative;
background: #8b847d;
}

#leftcol { 
width: 500px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Now what I need to do is that whenevr the height of leftcol increases the height of content should be automatically increased. Here is the fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/2y97A/

Comment: why dont u use jquery ?

Comment: @BhumiSinghal, please show me a sample?

Comment: is there any specified reson/sction through which the height of leftcol increases?

Comment: is there a reason for the absolute position?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, Actually this is pre defined design

Comment: @user960567 and you can change the style or not?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, yes sure if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make the height of `#content` increase when `#leftcol` height is increased because the `#leftcol` is positioned absolute. You have to remove `position:absolute;` if you want make `#content` increase its height.

**CSS Solution**

```
#content {
 width: 780px;
 padding: 10px;
 position: relative;
 background: #8b847d;
}

#leftcol { 
 width: 500px;
}
```

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2y97A/9/)

**jQuery Solution**

If you still want to keep `#leftcol` position absolute. You will need to use jQuery.

You can use the below jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").each(function() {
        var newHeight = 0;
        $.each( $(this).children(), function() {
            newHeight = newHeight + $(this).height();
        });
        $(this).height( newHeight );
    });
});
```

jQuery in action [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2y97A/11/)

Comment: I have to do this for abs pos like this http://lie-out.blogspot.ae/2012/02/how-to-push-parent-element-to-height-of.html

Answer (score 1):

What's the reason for keeping the absolute positioning? Easiest way would obviously be to remove it, but if you can remove it on just one of them (#leftcol), it can be done like this:

```
#content {
width: 780px;
padding: 10px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
background: #8b847d;
}

#leftcol { 
width: 500px;
float: left;
}
```